# Run server.product and open url [http: // localhost: 8080 / webui /] web error

Tags: http, idempiere

I used the source code from [iDempiere](https://www.compiere-distribution-lab.net/idempiere-lab/dev/idempiere71/).

- Running **mvn validate** is successful.
- Run **mvn verify** successfully.
- Import source into eclipse is successfully.
- Run file install.app is successfully.
- When run file server.app it will be fail.
- Run url `http://localhost:8080/webui/` failed.

Please guide how to fix the problem.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh3Rf.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you installed iDempiere on top of a JPiere database?

JPiere is a japanese distro of iDempiere, your error message is pointing to the error that jpiere theme is not installed.

For iDempiere vanilla is better to follow fresher instructions from here:
https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Installing_iDempiere

I can't assess about the accuracy of the link you provided as is in japanese - but I see it mentions Eclipse201909.  For running fine the latest version you need Eclipse201912 instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have fixed the error successfully.
Plug-in JPiere import missing.